# Ruby gem for SPNEGO-enabled HTTPS client

Tags: ruby, rubygems, spnego

I'm looking for a way to run GET and POST requests against a server that expects SPNEGO (credentials negociation) to happen. I would prefer a solution that works with Ruby 1.8.x as much as possible, though I will look at Ruby 1.9.x possibilities if I don't get anything else (have tried the gssapi gem with no luck so far - and I would prefer a spnego-able HTTP client rather than a DYI approach to it :/).

Currently, all my attempts have been unsuccessful (i.e. I didn't find anything that wasn't Win32-only - and I need it Mac/Linux-compatible).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was lying in the ruby bindings of libCurl (a.k.a. Curb). Yay!